# How to capture text in title bar of Android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I need to fetch the text present in the title bar of an android emulator. Any way to fetch it using java code?

[image]

Comment: surely you aren't making an app just for emulators. Can you share the usecase here?

Comment: it might sound weird, but I am. It's basically multiple emulators talking to each other and simulating a distributed system. And fetching the header text is a way to distinguish one system from another. I know there are many ways to do that but I simply can't find a way to fetch that header text!

Comment: Why not use something like device-ids?

Comment: I know. I'll end up using a similar thing, but still, how to fetch that title bar text?!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain port number on which AVD is running .
**This is what simple We can fo:**

1. obtain the phone number of emulator
2. last 4 digit of that phone number is Port no. 5554 or 5556 ....etc

**Java Code :**

```
        TelephonyManager teleManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String phNumber = teleManager.getLine1Number();
        String portNumber = phNumber.substring(phNumber.length() - 4, phNumber.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "Port number or Emulator Device Port is# " + portNumber);
```

**In Manifest File allow permission:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

On Api23 and above Use Runtime Permissions to read phone state. Hope this may Help you.

Port Number Helps yout o identify the Device

Comment: I have used this type of code before to fetch the port number. But there are instances where multiple emulators get the same port number because they both get the same getLine1Number() data. This is precisely the reason I need to fetch the emulator title bar text because that is always unique. And I could compute the port number from that.